# AppleScript that takes pictures of people

Tags: applescript

Im trying to make an AppleScript that takes a picture of by taking a screenshot of photoBooth. However, I cant set the window to one. Heres my code:

```
tell application "Photo Booth"
activate

set volume output volume 0


tell application "Finder" to set visible of process "Photo Booth" to false

set windowid to id of window 1 of application "Photo Booth"

do shell script "screencapture -l" & windowid & " ~/test.png"

tell application "Photo Booth"

end tell

delay 0
quit
```

end tell

Comment: PhotoBooth is not scriptable, it doesn't know anything about windows. Look [here](https://gist.github.com/iloveitaly/1054346) how to take a screenshot of the frontmost window.

Comment: You'd be better off scripting QuickTime Player (which can record using the camera)

Comment: I figured it out. 

    tell application "Photo Booth"
 
 activate
 set volume output volume 0
 tell application "Finder" to set visible of process "Photo Booth" to false
 
    end tell

    property N : 0
    set N to N + 1
    delay 0.1
    set picPath to ((POSIX path of (path to desktop)) & "Intruder[" & N & "]" & ".png") 
as string
    do shell script "screencapture -tjpg " & quoted form of picPath

    tell application "Photo Booth"
 quit
    end tell

Comment: Much quicker, use isightcapture command line. This shell command can be found on web and takes a picture with builtin camera and store the png or jpg where you want. basic syntax is 'path_to_isightcapture/isightcapture myFolder/file.jpg'. The path depends where you store that utility in your folders. You can even define the width / height. You can use the do shell script to run that command in Applescript

Answer (score 0):

```
  tell application "Photo Booth" to activate
  delay 2
  tell application "System Events"
      keystroke return using {command down}
      delay 5
  end tell
  tell application "Photo Booth" to quit
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**